# Insert "real" spaces when tab in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I hit tab in visual studio code, the code gets indented with what seems to be "fake" spaces. If I hit tab on a new line without typing anything on the previously indented line, the spaces on the previous line seem to disappear. Is this fixable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the unnecssary (because there is no text on that previous line) is being trimmed automatically.  To stop that disable the setting:

`Editor: Trim Auto Whitespace`

I think that'll result in what you want.